# pyspark regex extract all

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

I have a dataframe like below.

```
id  | js                                    |
0   | bla var test bla ..                   |
1   | bla function RAM blob                 |
2   | function CPU blob blob                |
3   | thanks                                |
4   | bla var AWS and function twitter blaa |
```

I am trying to extract the next word after function or var

My code is here.

```
pattern3 = "(func)\s+(\w+)|(var)\s+(\w+)"

df = df.withColumn("js_extracted2", f.regexp_extract(f.col("js"),pattern3,4))
```

as it is capture only one word, the final row returns only AWS and not Twitter.

So I would like to capture all matching.

My spark version is less than 3,

so I tried `df.withColumn('output', f.expr("regexp_extract_all(js, '(func)\s+(\w+)|(var)\s+(\w+)', 4)")).show()`

but it returns only empty for all rows.

my expected output is

```
id  | js                                    | output
0   | bla var test bla ..                   | [test]
1   | bla function RAM blob                 | [RAM]
2   | function CPU blob blob                | [CPU]
3   | thanks                                | 
4   | bla var AWS and function twitter blaa | [AWS, twitter]
```

Comment: can you try with my input, I tried but not giving expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use four `\` to form a regular expression.

```
df = df.withColumn("js_extracted2", F.expr(f"regexp_extract_all(js, '(function|var)\\\\s+(\\\\w+)', 2)"))
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can make your string a raw string and you'll only need two `\\` characters. More info: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: @AutomatedChaos Yes, Thanks. Another way is to adjust the ``spark.sql.parser.escapedStringLiterals``` parameter to ```true```.

Comment: can you help in escaping this regex to work with regex_extract_all (?:[\w$]+?\.)(?:[\w$]+?\.?)+

Comment: Can you give complete requirements, including input and output samples.

Comment: hi @过过招 , actually this solution works fine on my local but in my server the spark version is 2.4.7. May I know how can I do it on lower version..

error: `pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "Undefined function: 'regexp_extract_all'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.; line 1 pos 0"`

Answer (score 2):

use a positive look behind ascertion `(?<=i)j`.  That is extract `j` only if `i` is immediately to its left

```
df.withColumn('name', regexp_extract('js', '((?<=function|var)(\s\w+))',1)).show()

---+--------------------+-----+
| id|                  js| name|
+---+--------------------+-----+
|  0| bla var test bla ..| test|
|  1| bla function RAM...|  RAM|
|  2|function CPU blob...|  CPU|
|  3|             thanks |     |
|  4|bla var AWS and f...|  AWS|
+---+--------------------+-----+
```

Comment: actually the approved solution works fine on my local but in my server the spark version is 2.4.7. May I know how can I do it on lower version.. error: pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "Undefined function: 'regexp_extract_all'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.; line 1 pos 0"

Answer (score 2):

The question looks more like *how to do this without using regexp_extract_all* to me.

Here is another way without regex, just incase one has a problem of using `regexp_extract_all`:

```
noofwordstoextract = 1
df.withColumn("ArrayOfWords",F.split("js"," "))\
.withColumn("test",F.expr(f"""filter(transform(ArrayOfWords,(x,e)-> 
CASE WHEN x in ('var','function') 
THEN array_join(slice(ArrayOfWords,e+2,{noofwordstoextract}),' ') ELSE NULL END)
,y-> y is not NULL)""")).drop("ArrayOfWords").show()


+---+-------------------------------------+--------------+
|id |js                                   |test          |
+---+-------------------------------------+--------------+
|0  |bla var test bla ..                  |[test]        |
|1  |bla function RAM blob                |[RAM]         |
|2  |function CPU blob blob               |[CPU]         |
|3  |thanks                               |[]            |
|4  |bla var AWS and function twitter blaa|[AWS, twitter]|
+---+-------------------------------------+--------------+
```

This solution splits the strings into an array then checks the current element is in 'var' or 'function' and then extracts the next n words (here 1) and then joins them to form the original string (try with noofwordstoextract=2) for more details.